# Sending out an Email depending on data point using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, numbers, format

I am basically trying to send out an email if a certain data point is greater than or less than a max and min point respectively on the sheet. The thing is I set up the "If, Then" statement but it is not giving me the results that I wanted. Some text is even showing up and I am trying to only show the numbers that are in column "E". I wonder where I am going wrong.  I will specify in the code where I think I am going wrong. Also I am comparing with "K26" and "K25" respectively for Max and Min. Thank you for your help!

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub OutofControl()
Dim lRow        As Long
Dim lstRow      As Long
Dim toList      As String
Dim ccList      As String
Dim bccList     As String
Dim eSubject    As String
Dim EBody       As String
Dim vbCrLf As String
Dim data As Variant
Dim ul As Variant
Dim ll As Variant



Dim ws          As Worksheet

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True


End With

Set ws = Sheets(2)
ws.Select

lstRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(3, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)

For lRow = 1 To lstRow

data = Cells(lRow, "E").Value
ul = Range("K26")
ll = Range("K25")


    If data > ul Or data < ll And Not Null Then 
'THIS IS WHERE I THINK I NEED TO CHANGE SOMETHING SO IT DOES NOT DETECT THE TEXT



   vbCrLf = "<br><br>"

        toList = Range("B1") 'gets the recipient from col B1
        eSubject = "Text " & ActiveWorkbook.Name
        EBody = "<HTML><BODY>"
        EBody = EBody & "Dear " & Range("B1") & vbCrLf
        EBody = EBody & "Text :" & Cells(lRow, "C").Value & vbCrLf
        EBody = EBody & "Link to the SQC Chart:"
        EBody = EBody & "<A href ='Text'>Text </A>" & vbCrLf

        EBody = EBody & "</BODY></HTML>"



        MailData msgSubject:=eSubject, msgBody:=EBody, Sendto:=toList

        'Cells(lRow, "W").Value = "Mail Sent " & Date + Time 'Marks the row as "email sent in Column W"

    End If
Next lRow


ActiveWorkbook.Save


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True

End With

End Sub



Function MailData(msgSubject As String, msgBody As String, Sendto As String, _
    Optional CCto As String, Optional BCCto As String, Optional fAttach As String)

Dim app As Object, Itm As Variant
Set app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Itm = app.CreateItem(0)
With Itm
    .Subject = msgSubject
    .To = Sendto
    If Not IsMissing(CCto) Then .Cc = CCto
    If Len(Trim(BCCto)) > 0 Then
        .Bcc = BCCto
    End If
    .HTMLBody = msgBody
    .BodyFormat = 2 '1=Plain text, 2=HTML 3=RichText -- ISSUE: this does not keep HTML formatting -- converts all text
    'On Error Resume Next
    If Len(Trim(fAttach)) > 0 Then .Attachments.Add (fAttach) ' Must be complete path'and filename if you require an attachment to be included
    'Err.Clear
    'On Error GoTo 0
    .Save           ' This property is used when you want to saves mail to the Concept folder
    .Display      ' This property is used when you want to display before sending
    '.Send         ' This property is used if you want to send without verification
End With
Set app = Nothing
Set Itm = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried ISNUMERIC()? http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isnumeric.php

Comment: @Chrismas007 let me try. I will let you know. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `or` requires parenthesis to distinguish from `and`.  2. Code below will check for numeric value.

> ```
> For lRow = 1 To lstRow
>     data = Cells(lRow, "E").Value
>     ul = Range("K26")
>     ll = Range("K25")
> If data > ul Or data < ll Then
>   If IsNumeric(data) = True And isBlank(data) = False Then
>
>    vbCrLf = "<br><br>"
>         toList = Range("B1") 'gets the recipient from col B1
>         eSubject = "Text " & ActiveWorkbook.Name
>         EBody = "<HTML><BODY>" _
>         & "Dear " & Range("B1") & vbCrLf _
>         & "Text :" & Cells(lRow, "C").Value & vbCrLf _
>         & "Link to the SQC Chart:" _
>         & "<A href ='Text'>Text </A>" & vbCrLf _
>         & "</BODY></HTML>"
>
>         MailData msgSubject:=eSubject, msgBody:=EBody, Sendto:=toList
>
>         'Cells(lRow, "W").Value = "Mail Sent " & Date + Time 'Marks the row as "email sent in Column W"
>
>       End If
>     End If
> Next lRow
> ```

Comment: I am getting a Mismatch error and it is highlighting the "True" term? Why is that ? @Chrismas007

Comment: With the way the data is set up. There is space between them. And the blank spots are showing up. To fix that I used the code: 'And Not Null' but now it is not working at all. Nothing gets sent.

Comment: There is a space between what data?  As in when you define the variable data using `data = Cells(lRow, "E").Value`?  Also, you were using `null` before to determine if the value of `data` had nothing in it?  So what all is in Column "E" that you are looping through (as in what kind of data) and under which circumstances do you want your e-mail to be sent?

Comment: I made your update and now it is also displaying to Blank spaces I have in Column "E" and it is also showing data points that do not meet the criteria as well. I wonder why this code is not working? It seems like it would actually work, but it doesnt?

Comment: Tried some small syntax changes... give it a try.

Comment: I tried the syntax change, but I am still receiving blank spots :( At least its not showing the other data points and the parameter of  data>ul and data<ll is being followed. Its just that there area blank cells that are being read now.

Comment: Never mind it works now!!! I changed data Like "*" = True  to data Like "" = False . Thank you again! @Chrismas007! Much appreciated!